# R grouping by condition in data.table

Tags: r, grouping, data.table

In R, I have a large data.table.  For every row, I want to count rows with a similar value of x1 (+/- some tolerance, tol).  I can get this to work using adply, but it's too slow.  It seems like the sort of thing data.table would be good for - in fact, I'm already using data.table for part of the computation.

Is there a way to do this entirely with data.table?  Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
my.df = data.table(x1 = 1:1000,
                   x2 = 4:1003)
tol = 3
adply(my.df, 1, function(df) my.df[x1 > (df$x1 - tol) & x1 < (df$x1 + tol), .N])
```

Results:

```
        x1   x2 V1
   1:    1    4  3
   2:    2    5  4
   3:    3    6  5
   4:    4    7  5
   5:    5    8  5
  ---             
 996:  996  999  5
 997:  997 1000  5
 998:  998 1001  5
 999:  999 1002  4
1000: 1000 1003  3
```

### Update:

Here's a sample dataset that is a little closer to my real data:

```
set.seed(10)
x = seq(1,100000000,100000)
x = x + sample(1:50000, length(x), replace=T)
x2 = x + sample(1:50000, length(x), replace=T)
my.df = data.table(x1 = x,
                   x2 = x2)
setkey(my.df,x1)
tol = 100000

og = function(my.df) {
  adply(my.df, 1, function(df) my.df[x1 > (df$x1 - tol) & x1 < (df$x1 + tol), .N])
}

microbenchmark(r_ed <- ed(copy(my.df)),
               r_ar <- ar(copy(my.df)),
               r_og <- og(copy(my.df)),
               times = 1)

Unit: milliseconds
                    expr         min          lq      median          uq         max neval
 r_ed <- ed(copy(my.df))    8.553137    8.553137    8.553137    8.553137    8.553137     1
 r_ar <- ar(copy(my.df))   10.229438   10.229438   10.229438   10.229438   10.229438     1
 r_og <- og(copy(my.df)) 1424.472844 1424.472844 1424.472844 1424.472844 1424.472844     1
```

Obviously, solutions from both @eddi and @Arun are much faster than mine.  Now I just have to try to understand rolls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a faster `data.table` solution. The idea is to use the rolling merge functionality of `data.table`, but before we do that we need to modify the data slightly and make the column `x1` numeric instead of integer. This is because OP is using strict inequality and to use rolling joins with that we're going to have to decrease the tolerance by a tiny amount, making it a floating point number.

```
my.df[, x1 := as.numeric(x1)]

# set the key to x1 for the merges and to sort
# (note, if data already sorted can make this step instantaneous using setattr)
setkey(my.df, x1)

# and now we're going to do two rolling merges, one with the upper bound
# and one with lower, then get the index of the match and subtract the ends
# (+1, to get the count)
my.df[, res := my.df[J(x1 + tol - 1e-6), list(ind = .I), roll = Inf]$ind -
               my.df[J(x1 - tol + 1e-6), list(ind = .I), roll = -Inf]$ind + 1]


# and here's the bench vs @Arun's solution
ed = function(my.df) {
  my.df[, x1 := as.numeric(x1)]
  setkey(my.df, x1)
  my.df[, res := my.df[J(x1 + tol - 1e-6), list(ind = .I), roll = Inf]$ind -
                 my.df[J(x1 - tol + 1e-6), list(ind = .I), roll = -Inf]$ind + 1]
}

microbenchmark(ed(copy(my.df)), ar(copy(my.df)))
#Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# ed(copy(my.df))  7.297928 10.09947 10.87561 11.80083 23.05907   100
# ar(copy(my.df)) 10.825521 15.38151 16.36115 18.15350 21.98761   100
```

**Note:** as both Arun and Matthew pointed out, if `x1` is integer, one doesn't have to convert to numeric and subtract a small amount from `tol` and can use `tol - 1L` instead of `tol - 1e-6` above.

Comment: +1 Can x1 be kept as integer and just +1L and -1L handles strict inequality i.e. J(x1 + tol - 1L)? Should be faster to keep as integer.

Comment: @MatthewDowle we had comments roughly to that effect with @Arun, although I didn't realize that `1L` vs `1` makes a difference, probably should've left them here - the `1L` comparison indeed works for integer `x1`, but fails if the minimum distance between different `x1`'s is less than 1

Comment: @eddi Ah I see. For when `tol` is less than 1 (say 0.8 numeric) but `x1` is integer, how about `J(x1+as.integer(ceiling(tol)-1))`. And if I've understand correctly, maybe `rollequal` TRUE/FALSE could be added to data.table to build strict inequality in, alongside `roll` and `rollends`.

Comment: Btw: `DT[,list(ind = .I),]$ind` can be just `DT[,.I,]$I`. When `.I` is unnamed, the dot is automatically dropped so it can be distinguished from `.I` in any compound query on the result.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I think `rollequal` would be a useful flag

Answer (score 9):

#### See @eddi's answer for a faster solution (to this particular problem). It also works when `x1` is not an integer.

The algorithm you're looking for is [**Interval Tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). And there's a bioconductor package called [**IRanges**](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/html/IRanges.html) that accomplishes this task. It's hard to beat that.

```
require(IRanges)
require(data.table)
my.df[, res := countOverlaps(IRanges(my.df$x1, width=1), 
           IRanges(my.df$x1-tol+1, my.df$x1+tol-1))]
```

---

#### Some explanation:

If you break down the code, you can write it in three lines:

```
ir1 <- IRanges(my.df$x1, width=1)
ir2 <- IRanges(my.df$x1-tol+1, my.df$x1+tol-1)
cnt <- countOverlaps(ir1, ir2)
```

What we essentially do is to is to create two "ranges" (just type `ir1` and `ir2` to see how they are). Then we ask, for each entry in `ir1` how many do they overlap in `ir2` (this is the "interval tree" part). And this is very efficient. Implicitly the argument `type` to `countOverlaps`, by default is "type = any". You can explore the other types if you want. It's extremely useful. Also of relevance is `findOverlaps` function.

Note: There can be faster solutions (in fact there is, see @eddi's) for this particular case, where width of ir1 = 1. But for problems where widths are variable and/or > 1, this should be the fastest.

---

#### Benchmarking:

```
ag <- function(my.df) my.df[, res := sum(abs(my.df$x1-x1) < tol), by=x1]
ro <- function(my.df) {
            my.df[,res:= { y = my.df$x1
            sum(y > (x1 - tol) & y < (x1 + tol))
            }, by=x1]
      }
ar <- function(my.df) {
           my.df[, res := countOverlaps(IRanges(my.df$x1, width=1), 
            IRanges(my.df$x1-tol+1, my.df$x1+tol-1))]
      }


require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(r1 <- ag(copy(my.df)), r2 <- ro(copy(my.df)), 
               r3 <- ar(copy(my.df)), times=100)

Unit: milliseconds
                  expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
 r1 <- ag(copy(my.df)) 33.15940 39.63531 41.61555 44.56616 208.99067   100
 r2 <- ro(copy(my.df)) 69.35311 76.66642 80.23917 84.67419 344.82031   100
 r3 <- ar(copy(my.df)) 11.22027 12.14113 13.21196 14.72830  48.61417   100 <~~~

identical(r1, r2) # TRUE
identical(r1, r3) # TRUE
```

Comment: Arun, I tried your solution with a dataset that is more similar to my dataset, and got an error:

`    set.seed(10)`
`    x = seq(1,100000000,100000)`
`    x = x + sample(1:50000, length(x), replace=T)`
`    x2 = x + sample(1:50000, length(x), replace=T)`
`    my.df = data.table(x1 = x, x2 = x2)`
`    setkey(my.df,x1)`
`    tol = 100000`

Comment: Sorry - I'm having trouble figuring out the comment markdown.. The error is: Error in countOverlaps(IRanges(my.df$x1, width = 1), IRanges(pmax(1, my.df$x1 -  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'subject' in selecting a method for function 'countOverlaps': Error in .Call2("solve_user_SEW0", start, end, width, PACKAGE = "IRanges") : 
  solving row 2: negative widths are not allowed

Comment: Found the reason. Made the edit. Try it now. The problem was with `pmax(nrow(my.df)...)`... It's not necessary. The edit should work just fine.

Comment: Yup, works now.  Do you do much with Bioconductor?  I've been meaning to try it out for a while now.  I accidentally attended a Bioconductor conference a few weeks ago in Seattle.

Comment: Yes, I use quite some packages extensively for my work. They're mostly related to genomics, although a package like IRanges can be used on any interval data. Some packages are also submitted there due to licensing restrictions/differences in CRAN, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure data.table solution:

```
my.df[, res:=sum(my.df$x1 > (x1 - tol) & my.df$x1 < (x1 + tol)), by=x1]

my.df <- adply(my.df, 1, 
           function(df) my.df[x1 > (df$x1 - tol) & x1 < (df$x1 + tol), .N])

identical(my.df[,res],my.df[,V1])
#[1] TRUE
```

However, this will still be relatively slow if you have many unique `x1`. After all, you need to do a huge number of comparisons and I can't think of a way to avoid that right now.

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that

```
 abs(x-y) < tol ~    y-tol <= x <= y+ tol
```

you can enhance performance by a factor of 2.

```
## wrap codes in 2 function for benchmarking
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
my.df = data.table(x1 = 1:1000,
                   x2 = 4:1003)
tol = 3
ag <- function()
my.df[, res := sum(abs(my.df$x1-x1) < tol), by=x1]
ro <- function()
  my.df[,res:= { y = my.df$x1
          sum(y > (x1 - tol) & y < (x1 + tol))
          }, by=x1]
## check equal results
identical(ag(),ro())
TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
## benchmarks 
microbenchmark(ag(),
               ro(),times=1)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 ag() 32.75638 32.75638 32.75638 32.75638 32.75638     1
 ro() 63.50043 63.50043 63.50043 63.50043 63.50043     1
```

Comment: Part of it is the subsetting. With `$` your function is faster by roughly a factor of two as is to be expected. I have always problems to remember which subsetting function is the fastest. Changed it in my answer.